# pass HTML as variable in RAINTPL 3

Tags: php, html, raintpl

I am developing a website using RainTPL 3. I need to pass `recaptcha_get_html($publickey)` created HTML data to the tpl file and display it. But when pass this value using RainTPL variable, it receive in the TPL page as string. Not as HTML. Is there any way to pass HTML in RainTPL?

the output which I am getting in HTML page is where it supposed to give the output as captcha

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/challenge?k=myKey"></script> <noscript> <iframe src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/noscript?k=myKey" height="300" width="500" frameborder="0"></iframe><br/> <textarea name="recaptcha_challenge_field" rows="3" cols="40"></textarea> <input type="hidden" name="recaptcha_response_field" value="manual_challenge"/> </noscript>
```

Comment: Uhm... HTML *is* a string? I'll just wildly guess that you're saying that you see the literal HTML characters appear on the webpage... in which case, you're probably escaping the HTML when you shouldn't?!

Comment: @deceze : yeah..That is the problem. I modified the question. Is there any way to prevent it?

Comment: *Don't* escape the HTML. I don't know what templating system RainTPL is, but in Twig I'd do something like `{{ recaptcha_html|raw }}`.

Comment: BTW, skimming the RainTPL manual, it doesn't look like there's any option like `|raw` in it, at all. Adding some custom functions may or may not help. Frankly, I haven't exactly developed a high opinion of RainTPL from the bit I've seen of it, FWIW.

Comment: Got the solution. auto_escape is enabled by default in rain tpl. I jst change it to `auto_escape => false`. and it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the answer in a comment above. To find the answer easily, adding it here.

The issue which I found was `auto_escape` option was enabled by default. It will send the HTML as a string to the page. To avoid this behavior, disable auto_escape` by adding

```
auto_escape => false
```